# Testing file creation in Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am tryingto wite a test in robolectric on android. basically I have a class that writes serialized objects to a file. I pass in a context to the constructor and use that to call the method `getFilesDir()`

```
new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

I pass in `RuntimeEnvironment.application` as the context when testing but I get an assert failed when I call the below method to test if the file exists.

```
@Override
public boolean fileExists() {

    return context.getFileStreamPath(filename).exists();
}
```

I was wondering is there another way of going about this and using the test context to create the file. Thanks in advance!

here is the simple test iam running

```
@Test
public void testFileCreated()
{
    objmodelroom.createFile();
    assertTrue(objmodelroom.fileExists());
}
```

i create the file like this

```
public void createFile()
{
    this.objectfile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    objectfile.setReadable(true);
    objectfile.setWritable(true);
}
```

Comment: Are the file creation and existence check in same test method? Junit with Robolectric wipe test environment between tests

Comment: yes. i call crate file and chek it exists in the same test method. I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: I can not reproduce issue. Please check https://github.com/emartynov/robolectic-experiments/commit/3c457476e4093d1c09297c6dd44ea2d60ffcf155

Comment: i edited my question to inlude my fileexists() method

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: can you pass in a mock context

Comment: example when(mockContext.getFileStreamPath(anyString())).thenReturn(mockFile);
  objUnderTest.fileExists();
   verify(mockContext).getFileStreamPath(anyString());

Comment: no need for roboelectric. havent used that in years tbh